# If statement not being evaluated? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
# Inputs
annual_salary = float(input('what is your annual salary? >> '))
portion_saved = float(input('How much of your salary do you want to put away each month? >> '))
total_cost = float(input('what is the price of your dream home? >> '))
semi_annual_raise = float(input('Enter a semi_annual raise? >> '))

# Global Variables
current_savings = 0
r = .04
monthly_return = (current_savings*r)/12
number_of_months = 0
portion_down_payment = total_cost*.25
monthly_savings = (annual_salary/12)*portion_saved

while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    current_savings = current_savings + monthly_savings + ((current_savings*r)/12)
    number_of_months += 1

    if number_of_months%6 == 0:
        annual_salary = annual_salary + (annual_salary * semi_annual_raise)

print(number_of_months)
```

All this is supposed to do is evaluate the approximate months until a certain savings amount is reached. There is a semi-annual raise.

What am I missing?

Example with the expected outcome:

```
Enter your starting annual salary: 120000

Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal:​ .05 Enter the cost of your dream home: ​500000

Enter the semi­annual raise, as a decimal:​ .03

Number of months:​ 142
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-evaluate `monthly_savings` after applying the `semi_annual_raise`